# DS.FixtureAdapter is undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
window.Todos = Ember.Application.create();
Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

But DS.FixtureAdapter is undefined.
Ember version 2.2.0
Ember Data version 2.2.1

Comment: Random backwards incompatible change in Ember / EmberData. You'd better get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

The fixture adapter has been removed from ember-data. You can still use it by installing the `ember-data-fixture-adapter`, which you can find [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter).